# Blazor Server - Redirect to Login in Anonymous component - Sorry, there's nothing at this address

Tags: authentication, redirect, blazor-server-side

This is weird, I have a pge for user onboarding after he is invited to the app.

At the end of the onboarding process I wanted to sign in him programatically, but because its Blazor server component, it says that I cant change the header bla bla.. so I tried to redirect him to Login instead like this:

```
    private void OnReadyClick()
    {            
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/Login");                        
    }
```

Also tried like this:

```
    private void OnReadyClick()
    {            
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Account/Login");                        
    }
```

And just sending him to index and let the app redirect him when sees he is not authenticated:

```
    private void OnReadyClick()
    {            
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");                        
    }
```

Also tried in the component to add this:

```
if(redirect)
{
  <RedirectToLogin/>
}
```

All the options above make the browser return:

> Sorry, there's nothing at this address

But if I refresh the page it goes to sign in page...

Why is it returning upon redirect "Sorry, there's nothing at this address" and upon refresh works?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the force load parameter to your redirect:

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/Login",true);
```

But also, I've had this issue occur if you have render-mode="Server" for your app inside your _Host.cshtml file, instead of render-mode="ServerPrerendered".

Try changing:

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server"/>
```

to

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Daniel, I will check later if forcing the navigation will work. About the render mode is ServerPrerendered other wise Blazor Server will run like Blazor Wasm not doing the pre render

Comment: I believe the "ServerPrerendered" is the default one you get: "Statically prerender the component along with a marker to indicate the component should later be rendered interactively by the Blazor Server app." A bit unclear what this means to me, but I do know that if you use ServerPrerendered your OnInitialize code will run twice, so if you are fetching data etc it will do it once, then you may see the page refresh do it all a second time...

Comment: Yes exactly, that happens because "ServerPrerendered" first send an MVC to the browser the sends the SPA when it is loaded, this makes it bee faster then the normal SPA frameworks that are not server rendered. Changing to "Server" will make you wait for the SPA to load making it have the same behaviour as the "normal" SPA frameworks but still being server rendered. makes sense? :D

Answer (score 0):

Well after a while I still not understand why the browser gave me that response, but I solved the problem by using an anchor href like bellow:

```
<a class="custom-btn rounded-btn main-btn" href="Identity/Account/Login">
     @GenericConst.Ready
     <img src="assets/icons/arrow-right-ic.svg" />
</a>
```

Still would like to know the reason for the "Sorry, there's nothing at this address" msg, but if anyone ends up in the same situation just follow this solution.